# Can a S3 folder structure or file names degraded the performance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-s3

I have a folder structure on my bucket like this

AWS HTTP error:

> Client error: `PUT https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/application-objects/1550024b-18d6-44d1-922f-b1a54ab67763/feeds/prices_aud/chunk/prices_AUD.csv_1681724778.32_chunk0_1681724859.35`

Basically it is a folder where my application stores chunks of files and therefore the there quite a lot of files. On this chunk folder I have about 21,000 files and around 40GB of data.

The files are named like this and only the timestamp changes:

```
prices_AUD.csv_1681724778.32_chunk0_1681724859.35
```

I've noticed from some time the error rate increased quite a lot and getting a load of error messages likes this one below where seems to be timeout issue.

> resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:  `RequestTimeout`Your socket connection to the server w (truncated...)  RequestTimeout (client): Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed. -  `RequestTimeout`Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.

How can I debug this? It seems S3 was not supposed to have performance issue based on its data but maybe my file convention name or something could be affecting?

Comment: Read [Best practices design patterns: optimizing Amazon S3 performance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/optimizing-performance.html).

Comment: I've already @jarmod but didn't find anything that could explain my issue. it seems it is supposed to handle that easily.

Comment: You haven't provided any details here. What request(s) to S3 is your client making? What's the nature of the client itself? Programming language, SDK, runtime environment? Can you share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?